# Undo SVN CHECKOUT

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

There are multiple "undo svn checkout" questions on here, but none that I have found answer how to literally undo an svn checkout. Is there a way besides manually deleting? (Safer faster way than manually looking through a couple hundred files.)

I was checking out a directory via command line and instead of typing

`svn checkout svn://server/project/ .`

I typo'd and put 
`svn checkout svn://server/project/ /`

If you are missing what I am saying, instead of checking out the project to the current folder, it was checked out to the root of the server and now there are about a hundred files mixed in with the root.

Someone decided to put the `.` and `/` right next to each other on the keyboard...

Comment: This is why you don't work as root on your machine. You have to manually delete all the files and folders

Comment: I hear ya. I had to elevate to remove the directory, but didn't exit before checkout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
svn up --set-depth empty /
```

do the trick?

Comment: Not sure about the OP's situation, but this helped me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking is there an SVN command to do the work for you, the answer is no. You need to manually delete the files.

Comment: Or perhaps a safer faster way to delete all the files that were just added to the root.